# Crash on android app uninstall via Intent

Tags: java, android, uninstallation

why does my app crash when I try to call this function?

```
public void uninstall(){
    Intent intent;
    String packageName;

    packageName = HelloWorldActivity.class.getPackage().getName();
    intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse(packageName));
    startActivity(intent);      
}
```

Do I need any permissions to uninstall packages?
Do I need to add `.toString()` to `.getName()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Uri scheme for packages needs to have "package" keyword before the actual package name, so try this:
`packageName = "package:"+HelloWorldActivity.class.getPackage().getName();`